# Jquery sortable, where to put the ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I am a noob with JQuery, after doing a lot of searching on JqueryUI and SO I have found some code that I reasonably understand and that I have modified for my needs:

**http://jsfiddle.net/gmLfygwe/**

As you can see in the above link, everything works as it should. It outputs the old position and the new position into the console.

My questions:

1 - As you can see there is an ID for each list item, how do I get that?
2 - can you write a simple AJAX call for me that sends the old position, new position and ID to xyz.php via GET/POST please?
3 - Please tell me where do I place that AJAX code

I have a rough idea of the AJAX code, this is what I have come up with so far:

```
var formData = {id: theID ,oldPos: theOldPos, newPos:theNewPos}; //Array 

$.ajax({
    url : "xyz.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        console.log(data); // response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

but I am not really sure where in my code that goes (told ya I was a noob!) and how to get ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id from `e.toElement`: `$(e.toElement).attr('id');`

As far as where to put your ajax request, you just need to drop it in where you want the request to fire. Most likely in your event handling functions on sortable assuming you want to fire the request everytime an item position changes.

Comment: I figured out the ID thing :) but can you modify my JS fiddle example to put the AJAX part please?

Comment: For anyone reading this in future, other than the code prodigitalson wrote on top, even this works `$(ui.item).attr("id");`